The base group of a wreath product of an abelian group by $ {\mathbb{Z}}$ is a characterstic subgroup
Let $A$ be a finitely generated abelian group, and let $G = A \wr {\mathbb{Z}} $ be the standard wreath product. Let $B = \oplus_{\mathbb{Z}} A$ be the base group of this wreath product. I want to show that B is a characteristic subgroup of $G$.
If $A$ is finite, this is clear as $B$ is the maximal torsion subgroup of $G$. If $A$ is infinite, my idea is to show that $B$ is the Fitting subgroup of $G$, hence it is characteristic. I was wondering if there are any ways to see that $B$ is a characteristic subgroup, or if this has been studied before?
Any relevant reference will be really appreciated.

Now crossposted (and answered) at MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/480336/
